# Remove "wrong numbers"

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, math, statistics

I am trying to build a windows phone 7 app with vb.net

And i need to clear my listbox:

> 932 100 592 21 924 641 200 1230 5200 842 951 658

I would like to remove the "wrong numbers" because i want to get the average.
In this case the wrong numbers are:
too low: 100, 21, 200
too high: 5200

I just figure out a way to do this

```
For each items in listbox 
 calc the avarage
Next

for each item in listbox
 if item < avarage/2 then
 remove item
 end if
 if item > avarage*2 then
 remove item
 end if
next

for each item in listbox
calc the avarage
next
```

Comment: How about, you know, just *getting the average* to get the average?

Comment: How do you define a wrong number?

Comment: well below or well above average

Comment: @Gorfi: Problem with that definition:  Before you have the average, "well below or well above average" means nothing.

Comment: I just figure out a way to do this

For each items in listbox 
 calc the avarage
Next

for each item in listbox
 if item < avarage/2 then
 remove item
 end if
 if item > avarage*2 then
 remove item
 end if
next

for each item in listbox
calc the avarage
next

Comment: This may work depending on your definition of the outlier numbers. What about 80, 100, 101, 102, 105, 104, 140. Would you like to remove 80 and 140?

Comment: The avarage would be 104. only too low or too high numbers would be a problem i think,

Comment: *"too low or too high numbers"* is not a definition. Also, you didn't answer whether you would remove 80 and 140 in the series I provided. Any way, look at my answer and tell me if it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to find outliers in a series of values:

1. Compute the mean of all the points: `m`
2. Compute the standard deviation: `s`
3. For each point with value `v` if `abs(v - m) > s` then `v` is an outlier.

Here is the pseudo code to do that:

```
m = sum(v0, v1, ...) / N
diff = sum((v0-m)^2, (v1-m)^2, ...) / N
s = sqrt(diff)

for each value v
    if abs(v - m) > s then
        remove v
    end if
end for
```

Now, you have M values and you can compute their average:

```
average = sum(V0, V1, ...) / M
```